# Unbricking a hard bricked Meizu M3 Note

Tags: unbricking, meizu, flyme-os

I got an old and bricked Meizu M3 Note to fix it. The device isn't mine so I don't know what caused the brick. The device doesn't respond to anything - when clicking the power button or trying to boot into recovery nothing happens, just a black screen.

I tried following many tutorials on XDA and other sites, using SP Flash Tool, but nothing worked:

- [XDA - Meizu m3 NOTE L681H BRICKED!!! please help])https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/meizu-m3-note-l681h-bricked-please-help-t3700024)
- [Flyme Forum - Meizu m3 note Hard Brick Fix Tutorial](http://forum.flymeos.com/thread-36503-1-1.html)
- [XDA - [Developer Verified] [Tested] [Working] Meizu m3 note Hard Brick Fix Tutorial](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/developer-verified-meizu-m3-note-hard-t3682743)
- [XDA - [Guide] Meizu M3 & M3s Unbrick](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/guide-meizu-m3-m3s-unbrick-t3515231)

I tried flashing the stock ROM but still nothing. The device keeps connecting and disconnecting every 3 seconds when connecting to a PC using a USB cable.

After clicking the Download button in SP Flash Tool and connecting the device, an error message appears: `STATUS_BROM_CMD_STARTCMD_FAIL (2005)`

I'm pretty sure that the MTK drivers are OK because I used them to unlock the bootloader & flash TWRP on two other Meizu M2 Note devices and everything worked fine.

- Windows 7
- SP Flash Tool v5.1842

Comment: Please have a look at this video on MTK Backup & Restore using SP Flash Tool https://youtu.be/e2_U68EGSlY .. I've answered these questions many times, so for that reason i made a video on MTK Backup & Restores.... Ok so you need to backup your NV RAM and a few other thing's from the device ( in the description there's a link to specific image backups guide ) .. Once you have your backup you can do a device clone from another M2 using the info in the video and then restore the IMEI number etc....